# UITableViewCell setSelected method colors text label black

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is anyone else experiencing this problem where if you programmatically set the selected state of a UITableViewCell to YES, it colors the text label black?

[cell setSelected:YES]

I can't seem to figure this out. I would expect it to highlight the cell blue. Manually selecting the cell works as it colors the cell blue while the text is displayed in white.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem and fixed it by moving the `cell.selected = YES` into [tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:) instead.

I think it might be related to the note at the bottom of the UITableViewCell docs about changes to background color requiring use of tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath (presumably `selected` sets the background color).